# Constructing sequence of function with elements depending on the previous one / recursion

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, replacement, recursion, functional-style

Starting from a function $\theta0[x\_ , y\_ , z\_ ]$, the terms $\varphi[x\_ , y\_ , z\_ ]$ constitutes a sequence of functions that is constructed as follows:

Order 1 (one function and its reflection)
$$\varphi1[x\_ , y\_ , z\_ ]=\mathcal{H[z-z1]}(\alpha \theta0[x,y,z]) + \mathcal{H[-(z-z1)]}(\alpha \theta0[x,y,2z1-z])$$
$$\varphi1 R[x\_ , y\_ , z\_ ]= \varphi1[x,y,-z]$$

```
\[CurlyPhi]1[x_, y_, z_] := 
 HeavisideTheta[z - z1]*(\[Alpha]*\[Theta]0[x, y, z]) + 
  HeavisideTheta[-(z - z1)]*(\[Alpha]*\[Theta]0[x, y, 2*z1 - z])
\[CurlyPhi]1R[x_, y_, z_] := \[CurlyPhi]1[x, y, -z]
```

Higher orders use the results of previous one

Order 2 - use the results of order 1
$\varphi 2$ is obtained by substituting in $\varphi 1$, $\theta0 \rightarrow \varphi 1R$ so that is 
$$\varphi 2[x\_ , y\_ , z\_ ]=\mathcal{H[z-z1]}(\alpha \varphi 1R[x,y,z]) + \mathcal{H[-(z-z1)]}(\alpha \varphi 1R[x,y,2z1-z])$$
$$\varphi 2R[x\_ , y\_ , z\_ ]= \varphi 2[x,y,-z]$$

```
\[CurlyPhi]2[x_, y_, z_] := 
 HeavisideTheta[z - z1]*(\[Alpha]*\[CurlyPhi]1R[x, y, z]) + 
  HeavisideTheta[-(z - z1)]*(\[Alpha]*\[CurlyPhi]1R[x, y, 2*z1 - z])
\[CurlyPhi]2R[x_, y_, z_] := \[CurlyPhi]2[x, y, -z]
```

and so on...

```
\[CurlyPhi]3[x_, y_, z_] := 
 HeavisideTheta[z - z1]*(\[Alpha]*\[CurlyPhi]2R[x, y, z]) + 
  HeavisideTheta[-(z - z1)]*(\[Alpha]*\[CurlyPhi]2R[x, y, 2*z1 - z])
\[CurlyPhi]3R[x_, y_, z_] := \[CurlyPhi]3[x, y, -z]
\[CurlyPhi]4[x_, y_, z_] := 
 HeavisideTheta[z - z1]*(\[Alpha]*\[CurlyPhi]3R[x, y, z]) + 
  HeavisideTheta[-(z - z1)]*(\[Alpha]*\[CurlyPhi]3R[x, y, 2*z1 - z])
```

The final goal is to obtain the sum of $\theta0[x\_ , y\_ , z\_ ]$ and the terms $\varphi[x\_ , y\_ , z\_ ]$ in which only the function $\theta0[x\_ , y\_ , z\_ ]$ appears. An example output truncated at order 4 is given by:

```
\[Theta]0[x, y, z] + \[CurlyPhi]1[x, y, z] + \[CurlyPhi]1R[x, y, 
  z] + \[CurlyPhi]2[x, y, z] + \[CurlyPhi]2R[x, y, z] + \[CurlyPhi]3[
  x, y, z] + \[CurlyPhi]3R[x, y, z] + \[CurlyPhi]4[x, y, z]
```

producing

```
\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z - z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, -z] + \[Theta]0[x, y,
   z] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z - z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
   z] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
   y, -z + 2 z1] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z - 
    z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z - z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
      z] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
      y, -z + 2 z1]) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z + z1] \[Theta]0[x, y,
    z + 2 z1] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[
   z - z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z - z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
      y, -z] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z + z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
      z + 2 z1]) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + 
    z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z - 3 z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
      z - 2 z1] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + 3 z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
      y, -z + 4 z1]) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z - 
    z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[
      z - z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z - z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
         y, -z] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z + z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
         z + 2 z1]) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + 
       z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z - 3 z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
         z - 2 z1] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + 3 z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
         y, -z + 4 z1])) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[
   z + z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z - 3 z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
      y, -z - 2 z1] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z + 3 z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
      y, z + 4 z1]) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[
   z - z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z - 
       z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z - z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
         z] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
         y, -z + 2 z1]) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[
      z + z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z - 3 z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
         y, -z - 2 z1] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z + 3 z1] \[Theta]0[
         x, y, z + 4 z1])) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + 
    z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[
      z - 3 z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z - z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
         z] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
         y, -z + 2 z1]) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + 
       3 z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z - 5 z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
         z - 4 z1] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + 5 z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
         y, -z + 6 z1])) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[
   z + z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z - 
       3 z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z - z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
         y, -z] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z + z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
         z + 2 z1]) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[
      z + 3 z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z - 5 z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
         y, -z - 4 z1] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z + 5 z1] \[Theta]0[
         x, y, z + 6 z1])) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[
   z - z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z - 
       z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[
         z - z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z - z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
            y, -z] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z + z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
            z + 2 z1]) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + 
          z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z - 3 z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
            z - 2 z1] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + 3 z1] \[Theta]0[
            x, y, -z + 4 z1])) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[
      z + z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z - 
          3 z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z - z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
            y, -z] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z + z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
            z + 2 z1]) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[
         z + 3 z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z - 5 z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
            y, -z - 4 z1] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[
            z + 5 z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
            z + 6 z1]))) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + 
    z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[
      z - 3 z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[
         z - z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z - z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
            y, -z] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z + z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
            z + 2 z1]) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + 
          z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z - 3 z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
            z - 2 z1] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + 3 z1] \[Theta]0[
            x, y, -z + 4 z1])) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + 
       3 z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[
         z - 5 z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z - 3 z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
            z - 2 z1] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + 3 z1] \[Theta]0[
            x, y, -z + 4 z1]) + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + 
          5 z1] (\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z - 7 z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
            z - 6 z1] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + 7 z1] \[Theta]0[
            x, y, -z + 8 z1])))
```

My main issue is how to properly write this sequence of function.

Very naively, I first tried to simplify the expression by using the substitution operator, so that for example the second term can be written by using the replacement

```
\[CurlyPhi]2[x_, y_, z_] := 
 HeavisideTheta[z - z1]*(\[Alpha]*\[Theta]0[x, y, z]) + 
   HeavisideTheta[-(z - z1)]*(\[Alpha]*\[Theta]0[x, y, 
       2*z1 - z]) /. {\[Theta]0 -> \[CurlyPhi]1R}
```

This might reduce the number of typos, but it is basically the same thing as copying and pasting and it does not get me very far.

Then I understood that I have to add an additional argument to the function to describe the order. As a newbie to programming, what I did was to define the symbol to be substituted as an argument.

```
\[CurlyPhi]0R = \[Theta]0;
\[CurlyPhi]symbol[\[CurlyPhi]order_, x_, y_, z_] := 
 HeavisideTheta[z - z1]*(\[Alpha]*\[CurlyPhi]order[x, y, z]) + 
  HeavisideTheta[-(z - z1)]*(\[Alpha]*\[CurlyPhi]order[x, y, 2*z1 - z])
\[CurlyPhi]Rsymbol[\[CurlyPhi]0, x_, y_, z_] := \[Theta]0[x, y, z]
\[CurlyPhi]Rsymbol[\[CurlyPhi]order_, x_, y_, z_] := \[CurlyPhi]order[
  x, y, -z]
```

That allows to construct the two terms of the sequence $\varphi[x\_ , y\_ , z\_ ]$ and  $\varphi R[x\_ , y\_ , z\_ ]$ separately with `\[CurlyPhi]symbol` and `\[CurlyPhi]Rsymbol`, respectively, and I can use a table to write them:

```
Table[\[CurlyPhi]Rsymbol[
  Symbol["\[CurlyPhi]" <> ToString@(order - 1)], x, y, z], {order, 1, 
  4}]

Table[\[CurlyPhi]symbol[
  Symbol["\[CurlyPhi]" <> ToString@(order - 1) <> "R"], x, y, 
  z], {order, 1, 4}]
```

The produced output is indeed the symbolic required definition of each element separately.

Using `\[CurlyPhi]symbol`, for $\varphi[x\_ , y\_ , z\_ ]$ we have the following list, each element describing $\varphi 1$,$\varphi 2$,$\varphi 3$,$\varphi 4$

```
{\[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z - z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, 
    z] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + z1] \[Theta]0[x, 
    y, -z + 2 z1], \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z - z1] \[CurlyPhi]1R[x, y,
     z] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + z1] \[CurlyPhi]1R[x, 
    y, -z + 2 z1], \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z - z1] \[CurlyPhi]2R[x, y,
     z] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + z1] \[CurlyPhi]2R[x, 
    y, -z + 2 z1], \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[z - z1] \[CurlyPhi]3R[x, y,
     z] + \[Alpha] HeavisideTheta[-z + z1] \[CurlyPhi]3R[x, 
    y, -z + 2 z1]}
```

and using `\[CurlyPhi]Rsymbol` for $\varphi R[x\_ , y\_ , z\_ ]$ we have the following list, each element describing $\varphi R0$,$\varphi R1$,$\varphi R2$,$\varphi R3$

```
{\[Theta]0[x, y, z], \[CurlyPhi]1[x, y, -z], \[CurlyPhi]2[x, 
  y, -z], \[CurlyPhi]3[x, y, -z]}
```

However I got stuck at this point since I would not now how to map the proper association of the elements or perform the required substitutions so that I end up with a list of functions only $\theta0[x\_ , y\_ , z\_ ]$.

How would that be possible to perform the substitution?

Or, even better, what would be a more elegant version of constructing this sequence of functions? I feel that this is a textbook definition of some form of recursion but I cannot figure it out how to write it out.

Thank you all very much for sharing your knowledge and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the following code should do what you want:

```
\[CurlyPhi][0, x_, y_, z_] := \[Theta]0[x, y, z];
\[CurlyPhi][n_, x_, y_, z_] := \[CurlyPhi][n, x, y, z] = Simplify[
   HeavisideTheta[z - z1] (\[Alpha] \[CurlyPhi]R[n - 1, x, y, z]) + 
   HeavisideTheta[-(z - z1)] (\[Alpha]*\[CurlyPhi]R[n - 1, x, y, 2 z1 - z])];
\[CurlyPhi]R[0, x_, y_, z_] := \[Theta]0[x, y, z];
\[CurlyPhi]R[n_, x_, y_, z_] := \[CurlyPhi][n, x, y, -z];
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this is great! I would only add `\[CurlyPhi]R[0, x_, y_, z_] := \[Theta]0[x, y, z];` as a definition otherwise for n=1 \[CurlyPhi][1, x_, y_, z_] gives `\[Alpha] (HeavisideTheta[z - z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, -z] + 
   HeavisideTheta[-z + z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, z - 2 z1])` instead of what I should expect `\[Alpha] (HeavisideTheta[z - z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, z] + 
   HeavisideTheta[-z + z1] \[Theta]0[x, y, z - 2 z1])`. Does it seem right to you?

Comment: @DanielAmmering Done! I was wondering why I didn't get expected results.

Comment: Thank you very much Somos - it is a great help to me :)